# Adding an email into the card

Tags: trello

I've only just started using Trello but I've been told I can add an email link into the card. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just type in the email address in a comment or any other text portion of the card, it should be automatically displayed as a mailto link which will open the user's default email handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using an email address or using Gmail with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/z/7W/).

[image]

This Zap for [email to Trello](https://zapier.com/z/rK/zapbook/mailbox/trello/2092/add-card-to-trello-from-email/) gives you a unique email address like my_email@in.zapier.com and then you can send email to that address which will create cards in Trello.

Alternatively this Zap for [Gmail to Trello](https://zapier.com/z/Jo/zapbook/gmail/trello/2057/create-trello-card-from-email/) creates cards in Trello from emails you receive in Gmail that match the labels or filters you assign in the Zap.

Answer (score 1):

Refer **[Create Cards Via Mail](https://trello.com/card/create-cards-via-email/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1171)** and **[zapire Gmail Trello](https://zapier.com/zapbook/gmail/trello/)**